# iPhone In App Mail Compile Warning

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

My in app email is now working, but i'm getting a compile warning.  I would like to fix this, any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

I'm getting this warning.

/Users/vikings1201/Documents/iPhone Applications/LittleTipper_4.0/tipApp/Classes/tipAppViewController.m:1083:0 /Users/vikings1201/Documents/iPhone Applications/LittleTipper_4.0/tipApp/Classes/tipAppViewController.m:1083: warning: class 'tipAppViewController' does not implement the 'MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate' protocol

```
-(IBAction)sendMail {

    MFMailComposeViewController *mailComposer = [[[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init] autorelease] ;
    mailComposer.mailComposeDelegate = self;

    if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {
        [mailComposer setToRecipients:nil];
        [mailComposer setSubject:nil];
        [mailComposer setMessageBody:@"Default text" isHTML:NO];

        [self presentModalViewController:mailComposer animated:YES];
    }
}

- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller  
          didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result 
                        error:(NSError*)error {

    [controller dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's trying to protect you from setting the `.delegate` property to an object that might not implement the delegate methods.

In your .h file, you need to make it declare that it implements the delegate protocol.

```
@interface myVC : UIViewController <MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate>
{
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be pretty simple. You need to add  as an interface that is implemented by tipAppViewController in the tipAppViewController.h file. Something like this.

```
@interface tipAppViewController : UIViewController<MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate> {
```

You already are implementing – mailComposeController:didFinishWithResult:error: it just needs to be in your header file.

Answer (score 0):

`MFMailComposeViewController` expects to be able to send certain messages to its delegate.  The messages are defined as a protocol.  You are setting the delegate to an instance of your `tipAppViewController` class, but that class doesn't implement this protocol.  You need to a) implement the required methods, and b) define the class as implementing that protocol.

See: [Learning Objective-C: A Primer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/Learning_Objective-C_A_Primer/index.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007594)